# XSD definition for External Entity Processing

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML definition like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
    <!ENTITY roomConfig SYSTEM "room/roomConfig.xml">
    <!ENTITY roomStats SYSTEM "room/roomStats.xml">
    ...
]>

<mappingGroups>
    <configMapping>
        &roomConfig;
        &roomStats;
        ...
    </configMapping>
</mappingGroups>
```

I don't know how to write the XSD to define the <configMapping> node, specifically, the part which references the External Entity Processing (XXE) references: '&roomCofig;' and '&roomStats;'. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What have you already tried -- please post your XSD? To help you solve this issue, you will need also to show us the XML structure within the files "room/roomConfig.xml" and "room/roomStats.xml", because the content of these files will be *inserted* in the result document.

Answer (score 0):

External entities are a lexical tool, you can see them as a kind of macro mechanism.  The XML parsed from your example is an element `mappingGroups` containing an element `configMapping` itself containing anything contained in the 2 referenced files.

So a schema does not have anything to do with the fact that an XML document uses entities or not (external or not).  The only thing that matters as far as XML Schema is concerned, is what your XML document looks like after the entities substitution.  Probably something like:

```
<mappingGroups>
   <configMapping>
      <config>
         ...
      </config>
      <stats>
         ...
      </stats>
   </configMapping>
</mappingGroups>
```

And that is all you should keep in mind when writing your schema.